# How to record PCM streams and write to a AVI format file?

Tags: video-streaming, video-capture, avi

Currentl, I have a PCM stream, and want to record a segment of the stream to an avi file, which can be played using an avi-supportted media player.

I am wondering:

1. Any conversion is needed to record PCM streams to AVI file?
2. How to write the file header to avi file correctly, so that the media player can read it.
3. Is there open source library or tools which have avi file creation and writing?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use [ffmpeg](http://www.ffmpeg.org/) for this porpose.

```
For example :
    ffmpeg -i in_file -f s16le -acodec pcm_s16le out.avi
```